# How to set "A2SP sink" mode by default for bluethooth headphones (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, headphones, a2dp

Every time I connect my bluetooth headphones they go into `Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)`, which has very bad quality.

Who can I make so they o into `High Fidelity Playback(A2DP Sink)` by default.

I have seen other related answers but none of them worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have seen this reddit thread which suggests it's a know bug: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/85bqsz/bluetooth_a2dp_not_possible_in_gnome_gdm_without/

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Take a look here, it is for debian,  but it is worth to try. https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser/a2dp

Comment: Thanks but I don't see anything in there that targets my problem